# Project Euler Problem #6 - sum square difference

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

> The sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers is:
>
> \$1^2 + 2^2 + ... + 10^2 = 385\$
>
> The square of the sum of the first ten natural numbers is:
>
> \$(1 + 2 + ... + 10)^2 = 55^2 = 3025\$
>
> Hence the difference between the sum of the squares of the first ten
>   natural numbers and the square of the sum is \$3025 − 385 = 2640\$.
>
> Find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first one
>   hundred natural numbers and the square of the sum.

```
//Project euler problem 6

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

unsigned int sum(int);
unsigned int sqsum(int);

int main()
{
    cout << sum(100)*sum(100) - sqsum(100);
}


unsigned int sum(int n) // function for finding sum of n numbers
{
    return (n*(n+1))/2;
}

unsigned int sqsum(int n) // function for finding sum of squares
{
     return ((n)*(n+1)*(2*n +1 ))/6 ;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Once your code is working, we'll be happy to help you make it better but broken code is off topic here.  See the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) for more details.

Comment: A few hints: `sqsum` is not correct.  How many times does the loop execute?  What is the initial value of `sum`?

Comment: I changed my program . Please review it again ?

Comment: @Himagra Chawla
 does it give you the correct answer now? Until it does this is off-topic

Comment: I edited the code and now it gives me correct :)

Comment: Much better!  Now you can get reviews.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few comments that may help you improve your code.

### Use only necessary `#include`s

The `#include <cmath>` line is not necessary and can be safely removed.

### Avoid "magic numbers"

Since the constant 100 is used several times within the code, it makes sense to create a constant instead.  This also helps with troubleshooting since you can quickly change it to small values (e.g. 10) for which you already know the answer:

```
const int maxnum = 100;
```

### Avoid abusing `using namespace std`

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Especially in a very simple program like this, there's little reason to use that line.  Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Eliminate function prototypes by ordering

If you put the `sum` and `sqsum` implementations *above* `main` in the source code, you don't need the function prototypes.

### End the last console output with a newline

The output to the program is a little neater on most machines if you output a newline character after the last of the program's console output.

### Avoid unnecessary function calls

It doesn't make a huge difference in this code, but the code dosn't need to make two calls to `sum()`.  Instead, the `main` routine might look like this:

```
int main()
{
    const int maxnum = 100;
    unsigned square_of_sum = sum(maxnum);
    square_of_sum *= square_of_sum;
    std::cout << square_of_sum - sqsum(maxnum)-a << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `sumofsquares` stands first for **sum** and then **square of the sum**; despite its name, never for **sum of the squares**. Valid identifiers `sum`, `square_of_the_sum` are available. If you are feeling terse `s` (for sum) and `s2` (for square of sum) are also acceptable.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca: Good point, thanks! I've updated my answer to include your suggestion.